# Automatically select template's typename in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I'm working in a group and I have to deliver a `class template` which will be later composed into other classes like this:

```
template <typename type>
class foo{
};

class bar{
    foo<bar> a;
};
```

The `template`'s type will be always of the higher `class`.

```
class foobar{
    foo<foobar> a;
};
```

Is there any way to automtize/bind it, so that coworkers wouldn't need to always write the `typename`?

Comment: Note the way you want, no. You could use a preprocessor script to generate the code for you, or wrap the class declaration inside a `#define` macro.

Comment: Well, [The Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP)](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/05/12/curiously-recurring-template-pattern/) might be helpful to know as you could move the common code to a base class and have `a` member type be dependant on the class template parameter type.

Answer (score 7):

> Is there any way to automtize/bind it, so that coworkers wouldn't need
>   to always write the typename?

### the actual answer

No

### the pedantic answer

Yes, probably with some macros. But you really shouldn't.

### "So what should I do?"

Nothing

### "Why?"

Follow the "code is written once, but read many times" mantra. So just let them write the template parameter. It's just so insignificant of a inconvenience that the clarity of it far more outweighs the cost of a macro.

### "Ok, ok, I just wish there was a way"

So do I. And actually there is work done to bring reflection to C++ which should solve this (I hope, I don't actually know if it is possible with any of the two current proposals).

Answer (score 3):

Well you could add a class that would serve as a base class for you actual classes.

```
template <typename derivedType>
class foo_holder
{
protected:
    foo<derivedType> a;
};

class bar : private foo_holder<bar> { };
```

If you use private inheritance there, then it is mainly equivalent to you original code.

I am not sure if it would be possible to make the field private in base class and derivedType a friend of it. If so, then it could a bit less error prone (giving too much access to details which can lead to unnoticed abuses).